# Why do I get "method doesn't exist or bad signature"?

Tags: apex, httpresponse, compile-error

What am I doing wrong here? I have an `ApexClass` named `SearchController`, which starts with:

```
public class SearchController
```

and which includes these two methods:

```
public void save_search_results(String sanico_data) {
    System.debug(sanico_data);

    // Parse JSON response to get all the totalPrice field values.
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(sanico_data);

    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        // Start at the array of invoices.
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            // Advance to the start object marker to
            //  find next invoice statement object.
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
            JSONToken token = parser.getCurrentToken(); 
            system.debug(token);

            // Skip the child start array and start object markers.
            parser.skipChildren();
            }
        }
        }
    }           
}

public static void fetch(Search__c current_search) { 
    Http httpProtocol = new Http();
    // Create HTTP request to send.
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    String endpoint = 'https://sanico.com/v0/search/' + current_search.Name;
    request.setEndPoint(endpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');            

    // Send the HTTP request and get the response.
    // The response is in JSON format.
    HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    save_search_results(response.getBody());
}
```

I get this error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: save_search_results(string)

But I the method does exist and the signature is correct.

Calling `HttpResponse.getBody()` returns a `String`, which is what I give to the method, which is expecting a `String`.

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because your `save_search_results` method is not `static`, but your `fetch` method is. So the latter cannot see the former. Mark `save_search_results` as a `static` method as well.